# Where does github store comments that you type?

Tags: javascript, github, frontend, storage

Random question -- When you type a response into github where does it store the comment so that it can reload it when you reload the page?  I can't see any network requests going out or in with my comment, nothing in localstorage, indexeddb, ...

Apologies if this isn't the right site to ask this on, I'm not quite sure where to ask.

Comment: Probably through a socket

Comment: Nothing going out in websockets according to the network tab

Comment: Yup, I see that now, when you refresh the page it gets added to session storage, when the page finishes loading it is removed.

Comment: @Nicholas -- ahh, no wonder I couldn't find it.  Thanks!!